# Click automático no input ao abrir a página

Tags: javascript, html, html5, input

Coloquei um formulário para código de item no meu sistema, e quero que sempre ao abrir a página já esteja clicado no input, para que o código já possa ser digitado. Tentei de diversas maneiras porém não consegui nada que ao abrir a página o input já estivesse selecionado para apenas digitar o código.

(Quero que sempre esteja selecionado pois o código será sempre inserido através de um leitor de QR code, que lê o código e ja envia o formulário, e ao enviar o formulário ele recarrega a mesma página para que o próximo código seja lido.)

Segue meu formulário HTML abaixo:

```
    <form action="/separaItem" method="post">
    <input type="text" readonly="true" value="{{idCirurgia}}" name="idCirurgia" class="some">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>QR Code</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="qrCode" id="qrC" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit">Inserir</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: use o metodo focus()  [Elemento HTML DOM focus()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp)

Comment: Muito obrigado!! deu certo!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o atributo `autofocus` do HTML:

```html
<form action="/separaItem" method="post">
<input type="text" readonly="true" value="{{idCirurgia}}" name="idCirurgia" class="some">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>QR Code</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- O input abaixo terá o autofoco: -->
                <input type="text" name="qrCode" id="qrC" autofocus>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit">Inserir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_autofocus.asp